# How to understand if an object belong to a generic collection through introspection

Tags: c#, reflection

Let's say I have a reference to an Object. I'd like to use introspection to find out if it is a reference to a collection but I don't know (and don't care) about the generic type of the elements it holds.

As an example:

```
List<int> l;
Object referenceToList = l;

if (typeof(referenceToList) == ??)
{
  //condition is true for List<int>, List<float> ....
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you mean *reflection* instead of *introspection*?

Comment: @ken2k: unless the tag definition is wrong I mean introspection.

Comment: @ken2k: introspection is the reading part of reflection. See [the definition on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection).

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That's confusing. *introspection* is also something introduced by the FxCop API that is slightly different from *reflection*. See http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/introspection_code_model.html

Comment: @ken2k: Good point. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @ken2k: honestly I don't know C# so good to argue. Feel free to edit the question if you are sure about it.

Comment: Do you mean, test if some object is a collection or, test if some object is part of some collection?

Comment: @Jodrell: collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var type = referenceToList.GetType();
if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    // It's some List<T>
}
```

Comment: What about `LinkedList<T>`?

Comment: @SLaks: He asked about `List<T>` specifically.

Comment: @Hiesenbug, `typeof(IEnumerable<>)`, `typeof(IList<>)` or tautologically `typeof(ICollection<>)` may be more appropriate.

Comment: @Jodrell: Not in this scenario. He asked for a specific type. The code I showed is for a specific type. If he would want to check for a general collection, i.e. one of the interfaces you mention, he couldn't use my code because `object.GetType()` never returns an interface.

Comment: @Jodrell: No, that wouldn't work either, because we are talking about generic types here.

Comment: @Jodrell: You would have to use something like this: `type.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
    .Select(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    .Any(x => x == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: `.Contains(typeof(IEnumerable<>))`

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, would be possible, too.